# Hide Webform Title in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I have a Webform with various fields. At the time of display, title of the webform also displayed. I want to avoid that title. Is it possible to hide the title? Please help me...

This is the webform I created. I want to hide the title 'Contact Form'

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for what you're trying to hide ?!

Comment: I added screen shot above. Help me please....

Comment: Is this the `node title` ?! because I don't remember webform module adding any titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the title is coming from the node title then you can use http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle module to disable the page title.

You can find the settings under the content type settings. Do not that the settings you apply will be content type level. So titles of all the content for the particular content type will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the help in this context..Mean while i got another solution for the same issue, which i have tested and it worked fine. Attaching the same for a reference.." you can 'configure' the block and add  <none> in the title field, to hide the title from display"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using webform (D7), then you can hide title of webform (e.g. Contact Form) by going to **Block** -> **Configure the Block** -> type `<none>` in "**block title**" text box and Save it. 
See the screen shots below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably couldn't devise a worse way of doing it but in region--content.tpl.php I changed

```
<?php print $title; ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ($title!="Contact"){ print $title; }?>
```

.. it does work

Comment: `couldn't devise a worse way` you've been right imo

Answer (score 0):

My solution to a theme called "myTheme":

In myTheme/template.php add:

```
function myTheme_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state,$form_id ){
    if (isset($form['#node']->title)){
        $form['#node']->title = false;
    }
}
```